# Replace "\r\n5" Using javascript

Tags: javascript

I got a result "\r\n5".
  I want to remove "\r\n" and take only number 5.
  How do i take the number and remove "\r\n" using javascript replace function.
  please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use replace us this

```
"\r\n5".match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**trim()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method returns the string stripped of whitespace from both ends. trim does not affect the value of the string itself.,should be work

```
"\r\n5".trim();
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkXUu/)

Comment: I used trim function but it shows the same result